# How to get my uv maps to not stack everything together? (FIXED)

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

hope y'all having a great weekend. I'm pretty new to blender but these uv maps are KILLING ME! First, they'd disappear when I'd join two together. Now when I load them, the uv map is all smashed and stacked together. HELP I have no idea what's happening. Here is an image of what it looks like. Thanks so much for any help. I'm using 2.79 if that means anything. [image]

Comment: they should not overlap, you need to select all and unwrap once, not select each part and unwrap them successively. Anyway you can select the island you want in the UV Editor and scale/rotate/move as you want

Comment: Thank you moonboots. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid islands overlapping, don't unwrap each part of your mesh independently, instead unwrap all at once. You may need to create seams so that it unwraps correctly.

That said, from your current situation, you can also select each UV island with <kbd>L</kbd> and move/scale/rotate the way you want.

Comment: Yeah I found unwrapping individually was a lot better. Thank you so much moonboots!!